# Any way to check parameter before letting draggable be... draggable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a draggable widget in flutter... it has many things such as:

```
            onDraggableCanceled: (e, q) {
             // do something
            },
            onDragCompleted: () {
              // do something
            },
            onDragEnd: (l) {
              // do something
            },
```

But, I want to check if the object should be allowed to be draggable before it drags. Basically, is there a thing called,

```
allowedToDrag () {
// check if allowed based on parameter, and if it is then drag, if not, dont
}
```

Is there something like this I can do for my draggable? Thanks!

Comment: How are you using draggable widget? Just don't wrap the widget by draggable widget.

Comment: @SanjaySharma I am wrapping it in a draggable widget. My whole problem is that I have multiple draggable widgets on the same page and I only want 1 of those draggables to be draggable at the same time (not a problem maxSimiltanousDrags can fix).